# How does the car analogy explain refraction of light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

Today, my Physics teacher explained the cause of refraction by using the **car analogy**

It goes like this :

Suppose a car is moving on a concrete road and obliquely enters some mud. Now, one of the front tires will enter the mud earlier than the other and it will slow down earlier. So, this tire will now travel a less distance in the time in which the tire which has still not entered the mud will travel a larger distance. Due to this, the car will rotate with the tire that entered the mud as its center and its direction will change.

I get this. But I'm a little confused about how we can relate this to light while assuming that it is a wave.

An explanation would be appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this version of the same analogy is clearer for you. Instead of a car, we have a column of soldiers, say 4 soldiers wide, marching in perfect time. The column of soldiers is a better representations of the light wave than the 2 front wheels of the car, IMHO.

Now consider what happens when the column crosses the concrete / mud boundary at an oblique angle. The soldiers who step on the mud first will slow down earlier than the soldiers on the other side of the column, and the column will bend.

You don't even need a column of soldiers to achieve  this rotation effect. You can feel it for yourself by trying to walk along a boundary between a firm surface and sand, with one foot on the firm ground and the other on the sand. Your body will try to twist towards the sand. This gets very annoying within a couple of minutes. ;)

Comment: Nice version (better)- but I think the OP was confused because the analogy deals with particles and light is a wave.

Comment: @Krishna Exactly...

Comment: @Rajdeep The 2 front wheels of the car are a very crude representation of the wave front, the column of soldiers is just a bit less crude. That's why I said it's another version of the same analogy. Modern physics uses both wave & particle models for light. Historically, Newton promoted a corpuscular (particle) model of light, but the success of Huygens' wave explanation for refraction and various other optical phenomena dealt the particle model a fatal blow. It took Einstein's explanation of the photoelectric effect for the particle model to be revived. Wikipedia has more details on this.

Comment: @PM2Ring Light is a *Transverse wave* like all electromagnetic waves, right? So, this means that the direction of oscillation is perpendicular to that of propagation. So, the wave is somewhat similar to the graph of $sin(x)$. If we have a *longitudinal wave*, like sound waves in air going to water, then this analogy works fine, the soldiers are the *compressions* and the gaps between them are the *rarefactions*. So, this can be used to explain why longitudinal waves like sound refract.

Comment: But what about **Transverse Waves** like light and other forms of electromagnetic radiation. They have *crest* and *trough* instead of compressions and rarefactions. So, how can the analogy be applied to that? Let me know if there is something I don't know or have misunderstood about waves. I only have introductory knowledge in that. Thanks!

Comment: @Rajdeep The key factor is that light's speed is lower in a medium with a higher refractive index. When we combine that with [Huygens' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) (that every point on a wavefront is itself the source of spherical wavelets), then the light path bends.

Comment: I saw a video some time ago that stated the limitations of Huygens' Principle. It said tha if we make a diagrams with a lot of "circles", then different sets of lines start arising as well. I mean a different set of parallel lines with a different alignment that the first ones. Is that true?

Comment: And what do the lines in the diagram for Huygens' Principle refer to? Waves? I thought that was how longitudinal waves are, comprised of compressions and rarefactions. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, @Rajdeep I'm not quite sure what you're getting at. If you want to ask about Huygens' principle, you should ask a fresh question.

Comment: Check this out :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLmpNM0sgYk I didn't get much of it but this is the video that I was referring to in my last comment

Answer (score 0):

The **Car analogy** I was taught is that car is faster in concrete and slow in mud, so to travel from point A(in concrete) to point B(in mud) in the least amount of time, the car have to change the direction at the junction of the two roads. The explanation you gave doesn't have to follow the Fermat's principle, which is the fundamental principle in the phenomenon of refraction of light.

Comment: I  know what **Fermat's Principle** is. It does a pretty great job explaining **how** light will bend when it passes from one medium to another but I don't think it explains **why** it will bend. I thought that the *Car Analogy* was to explain why light bends...

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu your question didn’t ask “why” it asked “how”. If you wanted a “why” answer then you need to say so as well as explain your question in substantially more depth. “Why” questions are notoriously hard to frame in an answerable form: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp4dpeJVDxs

Comment: I thought that the car analogy explained **why** light bent as well as a bit of the rules that it followed while bending (another way to say **how**). I thought that the car/soldiers analogies do this by comparing light waves to wheels of a car or soldiers marching in a row and I wanted to know how to apply these analogies to light waves, indirectly asking **why** light waves bend by taking into account one of these analogies. And you quoted *Richard Feynman*, right? :)